# List of unique values for a property in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, database-design, gql, bigtable

I'm currently rewriting a python GAE app in Java, and am question my entity design.  I have entities like the following so that I could query the datastore and easily get back a unique list of designers:

class Designer

- Name : String

class Jean

- Designer : Designer

The code would be much simpler if I get rid of the Designer class since all it does is wrap a String, but I can't do a `SELECT DISTINCT Designer FROM Jean` to get a list of Jean designers.  Is the first approach the correct one, or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE(datastore-bigtable) doesn't support the complex query like SQL, So then you'll have to design your own model(db) structure like as you explained earlier.